# JS Loop thru new elements

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, for-loop

I have a for loop that is setup like so to screen for invalid inputs on the class and [required] on submit. It works for elements onload.

My problem is that this loop is not iterating over modified DOM elements ( new required fields  after window load)

**for example,** Checking a box to enable/disable new fields on the same form with attr [required].

**Question I have**
The for loop is failing to pickup the new required select fields (see code example 2 below) and passes validation regardless of the new required field.  Why is this and how can i remedy?

**Code example 1**

```
js_form.onsubmit = submit;

function submit(event) {
let not_pass,
    js_form = document.getElementsByClassName("validate-form")[0],
    text_inputs = js_form.querySelectorAll(".validate-input[required]");
    for (let t of text_inputs) {
      if (!t.value || t.validity.patternMismatch || t.validity.valueMissing || t.validity.typeMismatch || t.validity.checkValidity) {
        // show message to user of invalid input value and set not_pass = true
        
      }
      if (t.value && !t.validity.patternMismatch) {
        // remove message to user and validate false
      }
    }
if (not_pass) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log('All other inputs on page:' + not_pass);
      return false;
    }
    if (!not_pass) {
      js_form.setAttribute('form-is-valid', 'true');
      return true;
    }
};
```

**Code Example 2**

The below is checking for [checked] and modifying said fields with matching class and works as is but **the above loop fails to iterate over these new required fields**

```
let oasis = document.getElementById('oasis');
oasis.onclick = () =>  clicker1();
const clicker1 = () => {
  let oasisContainer = document.querySelector('.oasis-gwac');
  if (document.getElementById('oasis').checked === true) {
    let disabled = oasisContainer.querySelectorAll("[disabled]");
    oasisContainer.querySelectorAll(".disabled").forEach((element) => {
      element.disabled = false;
      element.setAttribute('required',true);
      element.classList.add("validate-input")
    })
  }
  if (document.getElementById('oasis').checked !== true) {
    {
      oasisContainer.querySelectorAll(".disabled").forEach((element) => {
        element.disabled = true;
        element.removeAttribute('required');
        element.classList.remove("validate-input")
      })
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: To clarify, i cant validate the new required fields. If this isn't clear, please comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was resolved by revising the way my functions were being called.  My entry file app.js was calling the an exported function submit() and not re-looping on each submit so im now calling the submit event immediately after the function submit and now it re-loops said new elements.